# Express POST request not working for button inside form tag in ejs file

Tags: html, express, post, ejs

I'm trying to send information from my frontend to my Express server. When a user clicks a button on the frontend, the post request the form is supposed to make is not working. There is no error in the console or any sign that anything has gone wrong. However, I know the post request isn't working because the request isn't being logged to the console.

My folder structure is below:

[image]

Here is my app.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render("dashboard")
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('button clicked')
    let item = req.body
    console.log(item);
    res.end()
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server listening on port 3000."));
```

Here is my dashboard.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
            "three": "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js", 
            "orbitcontrols":"https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p id="time"><span id="seconds">00</span></p>
    </div>  

    <form method="post" action="/">
      <input type="text" name='test'>
      <button type="submit" name="button">Test Button</button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are not getting even `console.log('button clicked')`?

Comment: @yousoumar I fixed the problem. An event handler was being triggered on the button click that I didn't know about. The event.preventDefault() method was inside the callback function passed to the event listener, which prevented the POST request from going through.

Answer (score -1):

The event.preventDefault() method was being called inside a callback function passed to an event listener which was listening for a button click on the button. This is what was preventing the POST request from going through. I was not aware the event listener had been added to the button.